# Webkit bug (?) - navigation justify

Tags: html, css, nav, justify

I have a justified horizontal navigation, but webkit always has a little space at the right end. Do you know what's the problem?

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navJustify">
  <a href="#">Link1</a>
  <a href="#">Link2</a>
  <a href="#">Link3</a>
  <a href="#">Link4</a>
  <a href="#">Link5</a>
  <a href="#">Link6</a>
  <a href="#">Link7</a>
  <a href="#">Link8</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav.navJustify {
   text-align: justify;

   background-color: black;
}

nav.navJustify:after {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}

nav.navJustify a {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;

   width: 12%;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

I made a jsFiddle so you can see what I mean (in Chrome/Safari): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSffa/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the white space in your HTML from the inline-block elements which are sensitive to it. Change the end of it to:

```
<a href="#">Link8</a></nav>
```

or

```
<a href="#">Link8</a><!--
--></nav>
```

**[jsFiddle example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xSffa/2/)**

**[jsFiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xSffa/3/)**